# Find equal row in table and add span before another

Tags: jquery

I have two tables, "AddFieldsToFormDiv" and "AddFieldsToPreviewDiv" and I need help to find the "QteOfOutPackSpan" span
in "AddFieldsToPreviewDiv" table (and add another span beforet that) if two inputs in "AddFieldsToFormDiv" are filled.

So far I have this:

```
    $("input[name='Volym1']").each(function (index) {
        var $QteOfOuterPack = $(this);

        var $OuterPackType = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='Volym2']");
        var $PreviewTable = $("#AddFieldsToPreviewDiv");
        var $row = $PreviewTable.find('tr:eq(' + index + ')');
        var $PackSpan = $row.find("span[name='QteOfOutPackSpan']");

        if ($QteOfOuterPack.val().length > 0 && $OuterPackType.val().length > 0) {
            $PackSpan.before('<span>Som text</span>');
        }
        else {alert('Do something else');
        }

    });
```

And [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63umF/154/) to play.

Comment: var capA = $('td input[id^=CapacityA_]'); --->  var capA = $('td input[id^="CapacityA_"]'); added ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
    $('#AddFieldsToPreviewDiv tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
        var $PackSpan = $(this).find("span[name='QteOfOutPackSpan']");
        if ($PackSpan.text().length > 0) {
            $PackSpan.before("<psan> i </span>");
        };
    });
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63umF/159/).